# zeroc Ice serialize Sequence of non-primitives

Tags: c++, serialization, casting, ice

ZeroC Ice serialization seems pretty easy for sequences of primitives or buildin types:

```
out = Ice::createOutputStream(communicator);
vector<Ice::Byte> data = ...;
out->write(&v[0], &v[v.size()]);
```

But how to serialize something different without suitable write method? I have to send a sequence of structs:

```
struct item{
    string name;
    ByteSeq data;
   };

sequence<item> ItemList;
```

How to serialize a ItemList?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. ZeroC automatically generates suitable write methods. [Just take a look](http://doc.zeroc.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5048839).